# Questions regarding offline contribution receipt

Tags: civicontribute

After checking the box, send receipt after entering in an offline contribution, where do I see the copy of the receipt that was sent?

After importing contributions, do we have to click Send Receipt manually for each contribution that was uploaded in order to send a receipt?

Thanks.

Roshani

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a copy of the receipt is stored in Civi - If you need to send a copy again you need to manually edit the record - set the send email flag and save the same that should resend a copy

Also for imported data/any contribution - you can use find contribution and select all the contribution and select the option of "Receipts Print or Email" this will send email for all selected contributions

I guess this helps !!!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with Transactional mail extension, can be found here https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional

It creates the activity of all the email that was sent.